# Is there a public website where I can test POST method?

Tags: web-services, http, rest

I am wondering whether there is a public website I can test POST http method with?

Comment: What do you want to test exactly with the POST method? There are like gazillions of public web site using it.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://httpbin.org/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know : http://www.posttestserver.com/

Comment: That site no longer exists.

Comment: That site doesn't work anymore, you can try this one. https://www.hurl.it/

Answer (score 5):

You want https://httpbin.org/

I couldn't remember the url and found this page as top result. The link is buried in a comment @Jefrey

If httpbin is down, in those cases I use https://httpbun.org/

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately the site referred to in the accepted answer no longer exists.

I used the [Rest Web Service Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-web-service-client/ecjfcmddigpdlehfhdnnnhfgihkmejin?hl=en) extension for Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

You can try https://postman-echo.com. Docs of how to use it are at https://docs.postman-echo.com/?version=latest, e.g., you can test a POST request at https://postman-echo.com/post.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if you want to use Android or Java at all. But you could easily setup a web service and a client as described [here](http://roderickbarnes.com/blog/droid-chronicles-web-services-part-1) and inspect the packages with a sniffer such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org).